# Regex between first and second "_"

Tags: r, regex

Hello guys i have a follow data:

```
data
proprio_com_luz
proprio_sem_ola_acabo
```

I want create two new variables

```
data                   condition variable
proprio_com_luz           com        luz
proprio_sem_ola_acabo     sem        ola_acabo
```

What regex help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `extract` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)

extract(df, data, c("condition", "variable"),
        regex = "^[^_]+_([^_]+)_(.+)$", remove = FALSE)
```

or with base R:

```
pattern <- "^[^_]+_([^_]+)_(.+)$"

df$condition = sub(pattern, "\\1", df$data)
df$variable = sub(pattern, "\\2", df$data)
```

**Output:**

```
                   data condition  variable
1       proprio_com_luz       com       luz
2 proprio_sem_ola_acabo       sem ola_acabo
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(data = c("proprio_com_luz",
                          "proprio_sem_ola_acabo"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not familiar with regex, then you can use this (not short) approach

```
> string <- c("proprio_com_luz", "proprio_sem_ola_acabo")
> out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(string, "_"), function(x) c(x[2], paste0(x[-c(1,2)], collapse="_"))))
> data.frame(data=string, condition=out[, 1], variable=out[, 2])
                   data condition  variable
1       proprio_com_luz       com       luz
2 proprio_sem_ola_acabo       sem ola_acabo
```